# laravel doesn't upload images on server

Tags: php, laravel

I can upload my images while i'm working on local but when I moved my site to host it doesn't upload images while get names of them in database,

my `filesystems.php`

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images/'),
        ],
....
```

sample of my upload codes:

```
if ($request->hasFile('imageOne')) {
  $imageOne = $request->file('imageOne');
  $filename = 'productone' . '-' . time() . '.' . $imageOne->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('images/');
  $request->file('imageOne')->move($location, $filename);
  $product->imageOne = $filename;
}
```

Issue:

> In host i get uploaded `image name in database`, but no image in my
>   `public/images` folder.

any idea?

## UPDATE

I found interesting folder in my host, as I moved all my `public` folder files to server `public_html` now it created another folder in my root called `public` and inside that has `images` folder including all images i uploaded so far!

**Questions:**

1. Why laravel created new `public/images` folder in my root instead of
   using my `public_html`?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: make sure you have right permission in your upload folder

Comment: @Ikong is that right?  https://ibb.co/iis4nx

Comment: yes its good. But you should not be using move() since it will just be in moving and not uploading see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads for the right function

Comment: @Ikong I updated my question please check it

Comment: seems like directory problem, can you also post your public/index.php? or you can check there if it has the proper directory defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SOLVED

I added this code to my `public_html/index.php` file and it's working now.

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should try to set that snippet in `register()` method of `AppServiceProvider`. Actually not to return `__DIR__` but rather `base_path('public_html')`.

Comment: @Tpojka meaning how?

Comment: Find `AppServiceProvider::register()` method and put in there `$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path('public_html');
});` so you won't need to change `index.php` file.

Answer (score -2):

I change the public path inside my save image controller to look like this:

```
if (request()->imagefile->move(public_path('../../public_html/destination'), $imageName))
     echo "Yap";
else echo "Nop";
```